# c# Regex.Split работает не так, как я ожидаю

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение `\(((?>\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>)|.?)*(?(depth)(?!)))\)`, которое позволяет выбрать все выражения в скобках верхнего уровня с помощью груп захвата.

Пример:

- Входная строка: `3 + 2 * (1 + 1 - (2 + 4)) + 12 * 31 - ((1+1) - 14 + 1)`
- Матчи: `(1 + 1 - (2 + 4))`, `((1+1) - 14 + 1)`

Я хочу разбить входную строку этими матчами с помощью `Regex.Split()`. Однако я получаю выражения уже без скобочек:

- `3 + 2 *`
- `1 + 1 - (2 + 4)` *- нет верхних скобок*
- `+ 12 * 31 -`
- `(1+1) - 14 + 1` *- нет верхних скобок*

Как я понял, оно выводит саму группу захвата, но **как сделать, что бы остались скобки?**

Comment: Это же элементарно, скобки подвиньте, `(\((?>\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>)|.?)*(?(depth)(?!))\))` ([пример](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%28%28%3f%3e%5c%28%28%3f%3cdepth%3e%29%7c%5c%29%28%3f%3c-depth%3e%29%7c.%3f%29*%28%3f%28depth%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29%29&i=3+%2b+2+*+%281+%2b+1+-+%282+%2b+4%29%29+%2b+12+*+31+-+%28%281%2b1%29+-+14+%2b+1%29)). Только вот такое регулярное выражение не очень надёжно, его лучше переписать традиционно как `(\((?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\))`

Comment: Не нужны тут регулярки.

Comment: @Qwertiy с regex это будет в разы кароче

Comment: @KuzCode, очень вряд ли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Split()` разбивает строку на части с сохранением *захваченных* подстрок. Так как в оригинальном выражении внешние скобки не захвачены, они отсутствуют в результате.

Вы можете поместить шаблоны скобок внутрь захватываемой подмаски:

```cs
(\((?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\))
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%5C%28%28%3F%3Cdepth%3E%29%7C%5C%29%28%3F%3C-depth%3E%29%29*%28%3F%28depth%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%29&i=3%20%2B%202%20*%20%281%20%2B%201%20-%20%282%20%2B%204%29%29%20%2B%2012%20*%2031%20-%20%28%281%2B1%29%20-%2014%20%2B%201%29):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C#:

```cs
var pattern = @"(\((?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\))";
var output = Regex.Split(text, pattern).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: большое спасибо!